# How to parse a string stream from pyserial and compare with a pre-specified value

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm finding it really hard to phrase this question, mainly because I've found the problem confusing myself.

So I have an IMU stream running from my Arduino and I'm streaming it through pySerial. Basically it gives me an output like this:

** #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11**

which is a continuous stream until I choose to stop it. What I'm trying to do is be able to pick the values individually and compare it a set value that I have already identified

For example:
Compare value #2 to a pre-defined integer b. I have not been able to figure out the code for that. Help would be appreciated. So far I have this simple code. It has to be in real-time.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM11', baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1)

def getValues():

    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    return arduinoData


while(1):
        print(getValues())
```

This is the output I get from getValues(). It keeps going until I stop it.
[image: a]

Comment: each call to `getValues` outputs a single value? Add a sample and the desired output, because it's very ambiguous.

Comment: Hey Marcos, just updated it.

Comment: you should post code not images so people can reproduce it.

Comment: The code requires 6 IMU's to be connected to an Arduino. It'll be difficult for people to reproduce that. So I don't think it's applicable. I simply want to be able to store each of the string values in real-time and compare it to a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to solve this issue, what I simply did was hold every value in my list into a variable. Since I wasn't planning on storing this data I simply overwrote on my declared variables and compared them with my predefined values in the loop.

Thank you for providing me with help.

Here's my code

```
import serial

while True:
    while(arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
        pass # do nothing

    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline().decode('ascii')
    dataArray = arduinoString.split(',')
    length = len(dataArray)
    if length == 13:
        TP = float(dataArray[1])
        TR = float(dataArray[2])
        IP = float(dataArray[3])
        IR =  float(dataArray[4])
    else:
        time.sleep(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `getValues` returns a string, you can store each value in a list for later analysis, for example:

```py
getValues = lambda: '0, 1, 2, 3, 4' 

values = []
i = 2
while i:
    str_values = getValues()
    values += map(int, str_values.split(','))
    i -= 1

print(values)
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now you can do comparisons with each values:

```py
b = 2
if values[2] == b:
    print('values[2] equals to b')

>>> values[2] equals to b
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Marcos, this solution definitely helped.